# Pandas get count with ancillary information

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'file_name': 'my_movie.mov', 'status': 'final'}, {'file_name': 'his_movie.mov', 'status': 'source'}, {'file_name': 'her_movie.mov', 'status': 'source'}])

       file_name  status
0   my_movie.mov   final
1  his_movie.mov  source
2  her_movie.mov  source
```

I would like to do something like:

```
df.groupby('status')[['status', 'file_name', 'count']]
```

`file_name` can be any file_name value, and count would be the `count` of records. The answer would be something like:

```
status         file_name              count
final          my_movie.mov           1
source         his_movie.mov          2
```

In SQL (using mysql dialect) I would do:

```
SELECT status, file_name, COUNT(*) FROM df GROUP BY status
```

How would I do this in pandas?

---

The closest I have gotten is this, but this isn't adding in the file_name, which I want:

```
>>> df[['new__status', 'file_name']].groupby('new__status').count().sort_values('file_name', ascending=False)
```

Comment: I don't think your SQL query is correct, are you grouping by both status and file_name?

Comment: @Reza -- no. I'm just grouping on `status`. Some sql dialects allow you to access fields that are not aggregated and just pull a random value from there (it's sometime called `ANY(...)` or `FIRST(...)`.

Comment: I see, so you need `any` in this case for Pandas?

Comment: @RezaI added an update to the question with an example of where I'm at now.

Comment: I just posted an answer, does it work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
df.groupby('status').agg({'file_name': 'first', 'status': 'size'}).rename(columns={'status': 'count'}).reset_index()
```

Comment: yes I just added on `.sort_values('count', ascending=False)` at the end and it works, thank you! But two questions here: (1) Why did you add in `reset_index()` at the end? What's the point of that? (2) Could you just add a couple links to the methods you're using? `rename`, `agg`, etc. ?

Comment: `reset_index()` is used to bring the aggregate column `'status'` as a new column instead of index. Here is the link for `agg`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `series.groupby` `NamedAgg`

```
df_agg = df.groupby('status').file_name.agg(file_name='first', count='count').reset_index()

Out[393]:
   status      file_name  count
0   final   my_movie.mov      1
1  source  his_movie.mov      2
```